# remove files which contain more than 14 lines in a folder

Tags: bash, shell, unix, grep

Unix command used

`wc -l * | grep  -v "14" | rm -rf`

However this grouping doesn't seem to do the job. Can anyone point me towards the correct way?
Thanks

Comment: rm doesn't read from stdin.

Comment: can't i form any regex for rm, which can indicate that the file is more than 14 lines.

Comment: @diablo8226: regexes don't do arithmetic. The string 99 doesn't match the string 14, but the string 2148 does.

Comment: @diablo8226 No reason for regex, replace grep with `awk`, i.e. something like `wc -l * 2>/dev/null | head -n -1 | awk '$1>14{$1="";print $0;}'`, though I think a loop makes more sense so you don't break whitespace anywhere. And as noted `rm` should come first, so if you want to do it in one line, it would be like `rm "$(wc -l .....)"`, but again loop is better to avoid issues with weird filenames that have newlines, spaces, etc...

Answer (score 2):

```
wc -l * 2>&1 | while read -r num file; do ((num > 14)) && echo rm "$file"; done
```

remove "echo" if you're happy with the results.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to print out the names of all files with at least 15 lines (assuming you have Gnu awk, for the `nextfile` command):

```
awk 'FNR==15{print FILENAME;nextfile}' *
```

That will produce an error for any subdirectory, so it's not ideal.

You don't actually want to print the filenames, though. You want to delete them. You can do that in `awk` with the `system` function:

```
# The following has been defanged in case someone decides to copy&paste
awk 'FNR==15{system("echo rm "FILENAME);nextfile}' *
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for f in *; do if [ $(wc -l $f | cut -d' ' -f1) -gt 14 ]; then rm -f $f; fi; done
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a few problems with your solution: `rm` doesn't take input from stdin, and your `grep` only finds files who don't have **exactly** 14 lines. Try this instead:

```
find . -type f -maxdepth 1 | while read f; do [ `wc -l $f | tr -s ' ' | cut -d ' ' -f 2` -gt 14 ] && rm $f; done
```

Here's how it works:

```
find . -type f -maxdepth 1    #all files (not directories) in the current directory
[                             #start comparison
wc -l $f                      #get line count of file
tr -s ' '                     #(on the output of wc) eliminate extra whitespace
cut -d ' ' -f 2               #pick just the line count out of the previous output
-gt 14 ]                      #test if all that was greater than 14
&& rm $f                      #if the comparison was true, delete the file
```

I tried to figure out a solution just using `find` with `-exec`, but I couldn't figure out a way to test the line count. Maybe somebody else can come up with a way for it

Comment: Don't use `for` to iterate over lines, use it to iterate over **words**. This will break for any filename with spaces. `while read line` is the basic idiom to read lines.